# Environment variable empty on echo

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables

I added an environment variable to /etc/environment like this:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
ENVIRONMENT_TYPE="test"
```

But it show empty when i try to "echo $ENVIRONMENT_TYPE", echoing out the PATH variables displays correctly. Why is my new variable not showing?

Comment: close the terminal and open it and test it again once

Comment: @TamilSelvanC I tried that but still not working

Comment: type `printenv` in terminal and show the result shown

Comment: try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/312406/how-to-set-environemt-variable-without-rebooting-ubuntu and let me know

Comment: @TamilSelvanC `printenv` displays the PATH variable but not ENVIRONMENT_TYPE.  Sourcing the file was the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after adding the values just execute:

```
source /etc/environment
```

Comment: This was the solution, same as Tamil Selvans comment

Comment: can you elaborate what that means please?